# Strange behaviour of uninitialized arrays and unset arrays

Tags: bash, array

I'm writing a script and I discovered some unexpected behaviour of uninitialized and unset array variables that I do not understand.

First of all, the length:

```
$ echo ${#notset[@]}
0
$ uninitialized=
$ echo ${#uninitialized[@]}
1
```

Why is the `uninitialized` length 1? Shouldn't it be zero? Is it because a null variable is considered an array of one null element?

This fact leads to some problems. For example suppose I want to create an array, and insert a certain number of things based on the user command line arguments. I thought I could do something like<sup>(+)</sup>:

```
myarray=

if [ some-condition ]
then
    myarray[${#myarray[@]}]=some-value
fi

if [ some-condition2 ]
then
    myarray[${#myarray[@]}]=some-value2
elif [ some-condition3 ]
then
    myarray[${myarray[@]}]=some-value3
    myarray[${myarray[@]}]=some-value4
fi
```

But this leaves the first slot to null, which I do not like and also breaks some code that I have written<sup>(*)</sup>, and at this point suppose that I want to see if the array contains any element. How should I do it?

```
[ -z "${myarray[@]}" ]
```

Raises an error if the array contains more than an element.

```
[ -z "$myarray" ]
```

Fails because the first element is null, even if the array is not empty.

So, how should I control that an array is uninitialized?

And could someone explain what exactly happens when dealing with *arrays* and unset - uninitialized variables?

---

<sup>(+)</sup> I know that I could avoid "declaring" the variable and it would work, but this script will be reviewed by a professor, and he does not like variables being defined at random places.

<sup>(*)</sup> Before trying this thing I was keeping the length of the array in an other variable, and so I did not have problems. But I'd like to avoid defining this auxiliary variables since I know I can obtain the length without them.

Comment: Note that `uninitialized` is *not* uninitialized; its first element is the empty string. `foo` and `${foo[0]}` are nearly interchangeable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the difference with `declare -p`:

```
unset foo
declare -a foo
declare -p foo
# prints declare -a foo='()'
foo=
declare -p foo
# prints declare -a foo='([0]="")'
```

If you want to initialize an empty array, the output of the first `declare -p` is a good hint on the best way to declare it:

```
declare -a array='()'
```

(The `declare -a` part is probably optional, a simple `array=()` should work just as well.)

If you want to test if an array has 0 elements, use numeric comparison on `${#array[@]}`;  don't try to do a `test -z` on the expansion as won't give the correct result in many cases.

Comment: I did not know of `declare -p`. Thank you for solving my doubts. The only thing that is not clear to me is your last sentence. I always used the `${#array[@]}` notation, why did you tell me to not use the other one?

Comment: @Bakuriu I was just trying to say that to test if an array is empty, it is easier to test if the count provided by `${#array[@]}` is 0 than trying to expand the array contents and testing if the resulting string is empty.

Answer (score 8):

To initialize an empty array, use

```
array=()
```

To add a value to the array, use

```
array+=(value)
```

Comment: Great, I did not know of this syntax. The only thing is that this requires to use `declare -a var` to avoid having the null at the beginning.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Initialize it as `array=()`.